# Android fragment re-use during re-orientation of screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm struggling a bit with my use of fragments for ICS.  I've got a fragment (call it AnalysisFragment) that does a fair amount of number-crunching work, reading in a file and then performing a number of calculations on it.  Most of this work is initiated in onActivityCreated, because I need to consult the app's settings file prior to doing the work, which in turn requires having the context, which is accessible through the activity, which isn't necessarily available until onActivityCreated is invoked.

Well, this work seems to be getting done again (twice!) whenever I rotate the display.  In my LogCat, I see onDestroyView and onDestroy happening (once), followed by onCreate, onCreateView, and onActivityCreated (twice), all pertaining to AnalysisFragment.

Obviously, the work of re-painting the screen for a different orientation has to be done over again, but is there any way I can add avoid the number-crunching work a 2nd time (not to mention a 3rd time)?

I maybe should add that I'm instantiating a new copy of AnalysisFragment whenever the user selects a new file to analyze, as follows

```
public static AnalysisFragment newInstance
(
    String ndsFileName,
    ViewIndicator viewIndicator
)
{
    AnalysisFragment analysisFragment = new AnalysisFragment( );

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle( );
    bundle.putString( "nds_file_name", ndsFileName );
    bundle.putString( "view_indicator", viewIndicator.toString( ) );
    analysisFragment.setArguments( bundle );

    return analysisFragment;
}
```

However, during a re-orientation, Android must be doing it for me.  After shutting down the instance I created, it instantiates another using the same bundle for the new screen orientation.  Eventually, onActivityCreated gets called on the new instance, and my code is off reading in the same file it read moments ago and re-doing the number crunching.

Any insight would be appreciated ...

Comment: Using savedInstanceState could be a good start to keep data between orientation changes

Comment: You said "onActivityCreated, because I need to consult the app's settings", but there's nothing preventing you from getting application settings in earlier fragment's cycle stages. All you need is the context. You can pass one in constructor or you can use any obiect that is subclass of context (like activity)